# PostgreSQL to add type Nvarchar?

Tags: asp.net, postgresql

Is there any suggestion for PostgreSQL to add type Nvarchar?

This is the error that I am getting:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42704: type "nvarchar" does not exist
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|194_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 42704
    MessageText: type "nvarchar" does not exist
    Position: 94
    File: d:\pginstaller_13.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\parser\parse_type.c
    Line: 274
    Routine: typenameType
42704: type "nvarchar" does not exist
```

Thank you.

Comment: try with `character varying`. [check here](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html). Also post the code along with error

Comment: you can usage. Postgresql = `[StringLength(64)]`, Mssql=`[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(64)")]`

Answer (score 2):

This error occured to me when my last migration (which the `update-database` command uses) was not for a PostgreSQL connection.

You can try this:

1. create a new migration with `add-migration <name>`
2. clear the database with `update-database 0`
3. apply the newly created migration on the database with `update-database`

Comment: I still get the same error after `add-migration`, what should I do?

Comment: I think this error comes up when you try to apply a migration on the ProstgreSQL database, which is made with a different connection from the Npgsql.You probably won't make the PostgreSQL db store an nvarchar, you should try to generate a corresponding migration.

Comment: This worked for me as I switched from a `Microsoft SQL Server` to `Postgresql 15` db mid project with a previous migration done against the former. Adding the new migration removed the error.

Answer (score 1):

"National" string data types are a vestige from the dim and distant past when people still used single-byte encodings like ISO 8859-1 or Windows-1252.

Nowadays we store data using UNICODE encodings, in the case of PostgreSQL, UTF-8. Since you can store any character that way, there is no need for a special data type.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, first I was using SQL Server as DB and changed to PostgreSQL. Old migrations were caused the problem `type "nvarchar" does not exist`. Deleted old migrations and created new migration, updated everything worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).